# HTML images don't render at the bottom of the long email in outlook

Tags: html, image, outlook, html-email

[post block code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eppGx.png) [outlook version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iyrw.png) [unaffected part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8AQ0.png) [affected area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiP6Y.png)
we sometime send emails with 40 to 50 posts in a single email, the images and content everything renders properly up-to 30 to 40 posts and after that it doesn't render profile images. we face the issue only on outlook desktop and not on outlook mobile app.

```
<td align="top" class="avtar" width="60">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<v:oval xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
style="height:70px;width:70px;float:left;" fill="t"
stroke="f">
<v:fill type="frame"
key="key" src="imagesrc"
style="height:60px;width:60px;float:left;"/>
</v:oval> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->

<img alt=""
class="thumbnail" key="key" src="imagesrc"
style="width: 70px;height: 70px;border-radius: 50%;border: 5px #d8d8d8 solid;" width="60" />

<!--<![endif]-->
</td>
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the affected area? Also, what version of Outlook desktop -- 2013? 2019? 
Other troubleshooting -- we know in Gmail it will cut off after 100kb of code; perhaps you can trial a few different sized emails?

Comment: Further to @Nathan's comment, if you could provide an example of the final HTML set you'd send, that would help us debug the basic block being rendered as well as see if there are any issues between blocks when stacked on top of each other. Swapping real content out for dummy content is fine too, as I understand you may not want to share your content. e.g. placeholder images - https://placeholder.com/

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for responding, I have added the screenshots you requested above, hope this helps!

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein Please refer the hyperlinks above for the screenshots. Thanks

Comment: @DheerajKumar If it works in Outlook desktop up to a certain point, and the code is the same block all the way through, then it doesn't appear to be a problem with the code. It appears to be some sort of limit with Outlook.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, thats what we thought, I will work towards reducing the limit of the email. meanwhile, I have a ticket raised with Outlook support to see if they have more answers.